# Record odd behavior in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-5

I've written unit tests using [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) library and faced with odd [`Records`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) behavior.

Assuming I have the code:

```
public record SomeModel
{
    //fields
}

public interface ISomeService
{
    public string DoSmth(SomeModel model);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private ISomeService _service;

    public SomeClass(ISomeService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public string MethodToTest(SomeModel model)
    {
        return _service.DoSmth(model);
    }
}
```

And I want to cover it with the Unit test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var model = Substitute.For<SomeModel>();
        var service = Substitute.For<ISomeService>();
        service.DoSmth(model).Returns("1234");
        var sut = new SomeClass(service);

        var value = sut.MethodToTest(model); //it returns Empty sting here

        value.Should().Be("1234");
    }
```

But it Fails, because MethodToTest returns Empty string.

If I change *SomeModel* from **record** to **class** it is working fine.

Could someone point me to what I missed here?

**Update**: I changed the model initialization in my test method:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var model = new SomeModel();
    //other code
}
```

In this case, it is working. But I still don't understand why it isn't working in the initial example?

**Update 2**. It is even working if I use *Substitute.ForPartsOf*:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var model = Substitute.ForPartsOf<SomeModel>();
    //other code
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's not even supposed to work with a class, because NSubstitute can only mock concrete classes in specific circumstances (that is, if they have only virtual methods). In any case it's a bad idea to mock concrete stuff, plus I don't even understand why you can't just instantiate your model object directly.

Comment: It is a very simplified example. In real-life cases, I can check whether my model method was called or not. Substitute gives more control, I can set only the properties that I need for specific test omitting set up an object to the required state